# AEM and ADFS and external IDP

Tags: aem, saml, adfs

Unfortuantely the built in AEM SAML Utility does not support the HTTP Redirect binding (only post binding). I have to perform SAML authentication to an external IDP which has HTTP redirect for both single sign on and single logout. Because of the AEM limitation I would like to configure ADFS to handle authentication with this external IDP and somehow get AEM to talk to that ADFS (either a federation service, or maybe an RP or claims provider). Does anybody know how this could potentially be achieved? I am assuming I could leverage the SAML utility or the SSO utility/modules in AEM (sling) to connect to ADFS somehow who will be responsbile to relay or proxy the IDP response to AEM.  thanks

Comment: In practice I have not seen the HTTP Redirect Binding to work with SAML due to practical limitations of URL length. Having said that I have seen it implemented using custom sling authentication. OOTB AEM SAML does not support it though.

Answer (score 0):

Using OOTB [SAML Authentication Handler](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html) there is an option **IDP HTTP Redirect**, I was able to configure SAML authentication with a redirect to ADFS and then after giving credentials, IDP was redirecting back to AEM with SAML2 response containing all the data, <strike>however, that was handled by POST Binding</strike>.

**EDIT:**, OK, I have just noticed that IDP HTTP Redirect option is not present in linked official documentation however on the [video](https://youtu.be/bfE16kc3JJY?t=189) in this [tutorial](http://www.aemstuff.com/blogs/july/saml.html) you can see it available on AEM 6.1... I do not recollect now if the POST binding is used at the end so that please check first if that might work with this option as I have used that before.

If you would need other solution, the fastest option I see is checking the default implementation of SAML Authentication Handler by decompiling (it can be done following [these steps](http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2015-09-16/decompile-aem-jar/), by at the same time I am only suggesting, not recommending that!) and base on it implementing custom handler adapted to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I instead used ADFS and created a claims provider inside ADFS, and used the AEM SAML utility to talk to ADFS.